# Where does the NBA league revenue come from?

Tags: nba, finances

I hear approximately of numbers such as 6 billion in annual NBA league revenue, of which 3 billion goes to team owners, and 3 billion goes to the players -- creating a wealthy "middle class" of NBA players, after a cap is implemented on the "max players".

Where does the 6 billion revenue come from?  Tv commercials?  Jersey sales?  International tv commercials, eg, commercials in China during games?

What about ticket sales? For instance, Oracle Arena sells out every home game -- do the Warriors team owners have to share ticket revenues with the league?  (I would guess so, since it takes two teams to put on a great game ... so the opposing teams are in a sense generating ticket sales at the Oracle ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6 billion dollars of annual NBA league revenue refers to all of the teams combined revenue through ticket sales at home games, selling jersey's to fans, season tickets, sponsorships, television rights, and adds on games. So to answer your question, their money comes from many sources. The league gets a percentage of all of the teams revenue through all the different streams of money and this can add up to a lot. According to Forbes, last year the NBA made 8 billion dollars with the average team being worth 1.9 billion dollars.